# Quaternification of a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions, clifford-algebras

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. A **complex structure** on $V$ is a linear map $J:V\to V$ such that $J^2=-\text{Id}$.

> **Remark 1:** if $V$ has a complex structure, then $V$ is even dimensional. In fact, 
>   $$
> J^2 = -\text{Id} \implies (\det J)^2 = (-1)^{\dim V},
> $$
>   which has no solutions over $\mathbb{R}$ if $\dim V$ is odd.
>
> **Remark 2:** let $W \subset V$ be a subspace with $\dim W = \frac{1}{2}\dim V$. Then $V = W\oplus JW$. Notice that, due to the dimension of $W$, we only have to check that $w$ and $Jw$ are linearly independent for any non-zero $w\in W$.
>
> Indeed, suppose that $ w = c\cdot Jw$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, applying $J$ to both sides of the equality, $J(w) = -c\cdot w$. Combining the equations, we find that $(1+c^2) w = 0$. Since $w\neq 0$, we must have $c^2 + 1 = 0$, which has no solutions over $\mathbb{R}$.

Analogously, let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. A **quaternionic structure** on $V$ is an *antilinear* map $J:V\to V$ such that $J^2=-\text{Id}$.

I believe Remark 1 and 2 above are reproduced in this case. However, the proofs presented above are not analogously extended to this case due to the following reasons.

> **Remark 1:** the proof fails since $(\det J)^2 = (-1)^{\dim V}$ has $\pm i$ as solutions over $\mathbb{C}$.
>
> **Remark 2:** The proof fails since $c^2 + 1 = 0$ has $\pm i$ as solutions over $\mathbb{C}$.

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Can you change it to considering $|\det J|^2$ (or $\det J\cdot\det J^T$), $|c|^2+1$?

Comment: Indeed. I have answered my own question below, and it is because $J$ being antilinear implies what you said.

Comment: Remark 2 is false. Consider $V = \mathbb{R}^4$ with $J(e_1) = e_2$, $J(e_2) = -e_1$, $J(e_3) = e_4$, and $J(e_4) = -e_3$. Then $W = \operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2\}$ satisfies $JW = W$.

Comment: You're very correct. [Apparently](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/beijing/2013/RealCplx.pdf), $W$ can't be any space, it must be the one fixed by conjugation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the problem was treating $J$ as a linear rather than antilinear (= linear conjugate) map. Remember that this means $J(av+bw) = \bar{a} J(v) + \bar{b}J(w)$.

> **Remark 1:** since $J$ is antilinear, $J^2 = J^*J$ and $\det J^2 =|\det J|^2$. Therefore $\dim V$ is even.
>
> **Remark 2:** since $J$ is antilinear,
> $$
> w = c\cdot J(w) \implies J(w) = -\bar{c}w,
> $$
> instead of $-c\cdot w$. Therefore we're actually looking for solutions of $c\bar{c} + 1 = 0$, although there are none.